# EEPROM or SD card storage for a general logger application?

Tags: microcontroller, eeprom, sd, storage

If you need to store data, let's say numbers (one byte each), and you need a capacity for at least 100,000 readings in a low power sensor (3.3 V and less than 20 mA in stand-by operation), will you go using an SD card storage type or a simple [EEPROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM) chip and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "stand by operation". You mean sleep? 20 mA is pretty high for sleep. I'd expect less than 100 uA in general.

I'd go with SD card storage. I've designed plenty of "low power systems" and the reality is that most people go to the trouble of going all the way to optimize for low power when in fact it doesn't make that big of an impact (it makes for nice marketing, but marketing doesn't always makes real-world sense). There are many other factors that are more important to logging:

1. Accessibility - An SD card is much easier and faster to read from and access (just take it out, pop in an SD card reader and it's done), and it's faster to do. EEPROM reading requires more equipment. An SD card can be accessed using a file system so it's intuitive
2. Capacity - You won't find anything better than a couple of gigabytes of storage. It's amazing how fast this goes once you start logging.
3. Ease of Implementation - Many commercial and open source applications have used [FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) which you can get for many microcontrollers. It will work nicely. Just open a txt file and save the numbers, one after the other.

An SD card isn't that power hungry. Some have power-down modes after 5 ms that will help.

I can't find a reason not to use an SD card.

Comment: SD cards can have high peak write current.  The OP didn't mention it, but run-time of the device might be a concern here.

Comment: They do, that's right, but it usually averages out if you write big chunks since it's also very fast. Perhaps he can buffer a certain amount and write all at once. That will definitively help with power consumption.

Comment: I would add, Cost! Cost of EEPROM is lesser than SD Card... That would be only disadvantage of SD Card, if I ignore implementation time/efforts.

Comment: @accessibility => for that to work, you need to use a proper filesystem on the SD, which requires quite a bit of software on the controller to implement.

Comment: @Swanand: Cost per  byte is much lower on the sd card. it's probably $1 per GB or less, whereas EEPROM is much much greater (several orders of magnitude i'd say)

Comment: @jippie: You're correct, and the OP didn't specify the microcontroller, but FATFS is freely available and has already been ported. It should not be that difficult to get it to run. In fact, if you look at how to organize the data without the file system, it becomes a nightmare.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky cost per byte is only relevant if you need more bytes than are in the base unit cost.  SD cards cost more at a minimum (unless you make the customer source them, but then you need an opening in the housing), and take more to support.  But when you need more than a handful of megabytes, or need removability, they do indeed start to look attractive.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Let me go point by point:
1) SD Cards do cost more
2) They don't necessarily take more to support. You still have to organize the data in the EEPROM, as well as create code to be able to extract the data using the system itself. I argue this is the same, sometimes less sometimes more, the effort needed to support SD Cards (for which code already exists).

Comment: Another issue is power supply reliability.  If power is lost while writing to an EEPROM, data in the part of the chip being written may be arbitrarily corrupted, but other data on the chip will be fine.  By contrast, power loss while writing an SD card may corrupt data which was, from a "user" perspective, not being written.  SD cards use "wear leveling" algorithms which periodically move data around the chip.  A good card should be designed so that at all points during a move, each piece of data will always be recoverable from either its old or new location, but that can be surprisingly hard.

Comment: If a bit that would mean "use the new location" gets half-written, a controller might on one occasion see it as having been written, and thus mark the old location for recycling.  If on a future occasion it sees that bit as not having been written, however, code would try to read the data from the old location which is now being used for something else.  Oops.